# layoutBody behavior differs between Grails 2 and 3

Tags: grails, grails-2.0, grails3

I have a componentized single-page webapp that relies very heavily on g:applyLayout, g:include, and g:layoutBody.  I have a workbench.gsp that aggregates numerous smaller widgetFoo.gsp files.  They are structured in such a way that each widget defines its individual JS and CSS dependencies and is fully functional whether it is rendered in isolation all by itself or when aggregated together with other widgets by workbench.gsp.

I am upgrading from grails 2.2.1 grails 3.1 and have encountered a problem.   I can find no explanation in any documentation, stack overflow, or forums.

The following code behaves very differently depending on which version of Grails I use.

workbench.gsp

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="workbench" />
    <title>Workbench TEST GSP</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Workbench</h1>

    <div>
        <g:applyLayout name="body-only">
            <g:include
                    controller="workbench"
                    action="w1"
            />
        </g:applyLayout>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

layouts/workbench.gsp

```
<html>
<head>
  <title><g:layoutTitle default="Heavy Meta"/></title>
    <g:layoutHead/>

</head>

<body>
    <g:layoutBody/>
</body>

</html>
```

layouts/body-only.gsp

```
<g:layoutBody/>
```

widget1.gsp

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>W1 - Grails 2 does not render this during layoutBody but Grails 3 does</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>I am widget #1 - Hear me Roar!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Grails 2 produces this:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>Workbench TEST GSP</title>
    <meta name="layout" content="workbench">
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Workbench</h1>

    <div>
        <h1>I am widget #1 - Hear me Roar!</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Grails 3 produces this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="layout" content="workbench">
    <title>Workbench TEST GSP</title>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>Workbench</h1>

    <div>
        <title>W1 - Grails 2 does not render this during layoutBody but Grails 3 does</title>
        <h1>I am widget #1 - Hear me Roar!</h1>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

It may seem minor in this trivial example, but, when I put more than one widget on the page, it gets worse.  And when their head elements include   and  where ONE and TWO have overlapping dependencies, all hell breaks loose.  So, I thought I would present my problem in what seems to be its most fundamental form first and work forward from there.

Any insights?

Comment: from what I see you have designed from the word up incorrect pages so for example  action="w1" should then render a template which doesn't include existing bod information or simply adding if (request.xhr) { render template:'' } otherwise render view - In any case it is badly written gsps that are now biting - so you can fix it most easily by correcting the structure to load in templates where it should be templates and gsp views where it should be views

Comment: @vahid thanks for taking the time to respond.  You can be forgiven for misunderstanding the question I hadn't asked: how do I declare my dependencies?  I think you assumed that I would declare them in my GSP.  I wouldn't.  I had declared my JS dependencies in my JS files, the obviously correct approach.  I wound up on a variation of your suggestion in which I moved the shared dependencies into a layout which is used by the widget GSPs individually but bypassed by the aggregating workbench GSP.